# How can I write a function for getting all the files without repeating the path each time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

My complete function:

```
def Unzip(APP_NAME, ASSETS_PATH):
    nameDir=ASSETS_PATH+"\\unzip\\"

    print "[INFO] Unzipping"
    a=1
    files=[]
    file_name = APP_NAME.split("/")
    file_name = file_name[-1]
    out_dir = ASSETS_PATH+"/unzip/"+file_name+"_"+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y%H%M%S")
    try:
        files = []
        with zipfile.ZipFile(APP_NAME, "r") as z:
            for fileinfo in z.infolist():
                dat = z.open(fileinfo.filename, "r")
                filename = fileinfo.filename
                if not isinstance(filename, unicode):
                    filename = unicode(fileinfo.filename, encoding="utf-8", errors="replace")
                files.append(filename)
                outfile = os.path.join(out_dir, filename)
                if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(outfile)):
                    try:
                        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(outfile))
                    except OSError as exc:
                        if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                            print "\n[WARN] OS Error: Race Condition"
                if not outfile.endswith("/"):
                    with io.open(outfile, mode='wb') as f:
                        f.write(dat.read())
                dat.close()
                a=a+1
                print a
        return files, out_dir
```

The structure of my files is like this:

```
|--a
|  |--a
|  |--b
|  |  |--a.txt
|  |
|  |--c
|
|--b
|  |--a
|     |--a.txt
|     |--b.txt
|
|--c
|  |--a.txt         
|  |--b.txt
|
|--d
```

Where *a.txt* and *b.txt* are filse and *a*, *b*, *c*, *d* are directories.

I want to create a dict that takes into consideration the depth of the files in the tree.

How can I write a function for getting all the files **but without repeating the path each time**?

All inside the FOR-cycle that already exists.

The result should be like when I enter into the properties of object.

Comment: It's not clear what result you are trying to achieve when you say "should be like when I enter into the propertys of object."

Comment: @air The end date must be a dictionary with depth to see the file and directory level.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `os.walk("root path ")`

Comment: How can I handle it in my function?

Answer (score 0):

This function return all files without repeat as a list of string

```
def get_files(path1):
    res =[]
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path1):
        for name in files:
            res.append(os.path.join(path, name))
    return list(set(res))
    list(set(res))
```

Comment: How can I handle it in my function?

Comment: If you want to get all files of certain path just replace your function by this function